# Angular PWA display:standalone not working on Android

Tags: android, angular, progressive-web-apps

[This Angular app](https://azureadb2ctesting1.z9.web.core.windows.net/) has been packaged as an Android application using [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/). When installing the APK on an Android device, the PWA still displays a URL bar at the top of the application window. What can be done to make "display": "standalone" work on an Android device?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "azureadb2ctesting1",
  "short_name": "azureadb2ctesting1",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder called `.well-known` in the public directory of the app and place the `assetlinks.json` file into that folder. This will remove the top bar. It is done in order to verify that you're the owner of the particular hosting.